# Automate OneDrive for Business 2013

Tags: ms-office

Can anyone refer any link or resource location to automate OneDrive for Business with SharePoint Online. I need to fetch the libraries already added to "OneDrive for Business", also allow from a custom screen to add new library or delete an existing library from "OneDrive for Business".

Would appreciate any hint how I can create a desktop application for Windows 7 which will provide all functionality for OneDrive and add more (which is not in OneDrive tool - eg, check in menu, checkout menu, version menu etc.